# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while uploading an encrypted PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, exception, itext

I am getting the following exception when I am trying to upload a password protected PDF file in my application:

How to solve this problem? I tried different itext versions but still the same error. Is there anyway I can solve this issue? Thanks.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.<init>(PdfEncryption.java:138)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj(PdfReader.java:762)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDocObj(PdfReader.java:1133)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:511)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:171)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:160)
    at com.quepio.web.controller.TutoContentController.processChapterContent(TutoContentController.java:2582)
    at com.quepio.web.controller.TutoContentController.saveOrUpdateContent(TutoContentController.java:1694)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.quepio.web.TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.quepio.web.FirstLoginFilter.doFilterInternal(FirstLoginFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
```

I am using the following jars.

```
itext: 5.3.2
bcprov-jdk15on: 1.47
bcmail-jdk15on: 1.47
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the POM file that ships with iText: [pom.xml](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/master/pom.xml)

You'll discover that the current version of iText is 5.5.7:

```
<artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>iText, a Free Java-PDF library</name>
<version>5.5.7</version>
<description>iText, a free Java-PDF library</description>
```

Now scroll down to the dependencies and look for BouncyCastle:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

As you can see, the BC version that works with 5.5.7 is BC 1.49.

The POM files are provided, so that developers don't have to resort to "trial and error." If you are familiar with Maven, just use the POM file and you don't have to worry about which BouncyCastle version to use. All the dependencies will be downloaded automatically through Maven.

Of course: you have to make sure that BC is also available in the CLASSPATH of your server. You also need to take special care to make sure that you have **only one version** of BouncyCastle. A `ClassNotFoundException` doesn't always mean that the class isn't present. It can also mean that there's an ambiguity. If you have a class named `DEREncodable` in one version of BC that is in your CLASSPATH and a class with the same name in another version of BC that is in your class path, the JVM won't know which class to use and will also throw a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Concerning the ambiguity... Usually in that case the first class found on the class path is used and no exception thrown. But in many cases that might be the wrong choice. Furthermore there usually are multiple class loaders involved complicating matters somewhat.

Comment: The ambiguity problem is inherent to BC. They did a major upgrade, changing some package names, but not all. If you first use a class of one version that exists in both versions, and you then need a class that is available in only one version, you can get some very curious errors, especially on Android. For that reason, we use SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle in the Android port of iText.

Comment: Yes, you do indeed get funny error messages in case of multiple installed conflicting BC versions. But usually you don't get *class not found*, but instead something like *method not found in class* or *method tries to override final method* etc... *class not found* more often indicates either simply a wrong BC version or the (possibly) right BC version in the classpath of the wrong class loader.

Comment: hey..thanks for replying. I tried with iText  5.5.7. As u said i added the corresponding jars as listed in POM file. I am using ANT not maven. So i added those dependency jars also.confirmed in class path too. Still i am getting same exception

Comment: The best (and IMO only) way to solve these kind of problems, is by throwing away everything you have and start over with a clean installation (project, server environment, etc.). This is a problem that can't be solved by anyone else but you.